# Error code 4717 when installing B&R Automation Studio 4.12

Tags: br-automation-studio

[image: Error code]

What can I do? The installation of `Automation Studio 4.12` got aborted because of `AR SG3 V2.40` with the error code 4717. What is the reason for it?

I have already installed `.NET Framework 3.5` and I have `Windows 11` on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

I also got this error when installing on a folder I created. I have named this folder B&R. When installing the single package AR SG3 then came the error that the specified path contains special characters. Just write the installation folder without special characters (example: B_R) and then the installation goes through.